# RequireJS - loading a plugin that has its own requirements

Tags: jquery, requirejs

There is a possibility that I am over complicating this issue, but hopefully it's a quick fix. I'm trying to load in a jQuery plugin in a requireJS module in which this plugins has its own available plugins (FooTables). So, I assume, that I need the jQuery plugin itself already loaded in on jQuery before I attempt to require the other plugins. I thought about using jQuery's deferred to trigger inside of another require when the plugins were done loading, but it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. I'm assuming there's some sort of race condition. Any input would be awesome.

Here's the code I currently have. I'm loading in jQuery initially, then loading in Footables, and then a require to load in the plugins at which point I resolve the deferred.

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var plugins = [
        'vendor/plugins/footables/footable',
        'vendor/plugins/footables/footable.filter',
        'vendor/plugins/footables/footable.sort',
        'vendor/plugins/footables/footable.striping'
    ];

    require([
        'jquery',
        'vendor/plugins/footables/footable'
    ],function(){
        require(plugins, function(){
            deferred.resolve($);
        })
    });

    deferred.done(function($){
        $('#footable-0').footable();
        $('#footable-0').removeAttr('hidden');
    })

});
```

My RequireJS config is as follows:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery':          '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min',
        'jquery-ui':       'vendor/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom',
        'leaflet':         'widgets/leafletjs_wrapper'
    },
    // avoid jquery conflicts on the page, per http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap
    map: {
        '*': { 'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-private' },
        'vendor/jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    }
    });
require(['app', 'jquery'], function (app, $) {
    'use strict';
});
```

I then start the app with app.js, which simply loads in jQuery and the module that I'm trying to run.

```
define([
    'widgets/footables_wrapper'
], function () {
    'use strict';
    return {};
});
```

Everything else is loading in as it should. I'm wondering if I need to shim the plugins since I don't believe they are AMD modules, but does that mean an individual shim for each individual plugin? Is there a way to do a dependency for multiple files?

Or possibly I'm not passing the $ variable around correctly so that when it is passed in to the deferred.resolve it doesn't have the FooTables functions (and all of the plugins) properly attached. Just some thoughts.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get errors? Is it failing to do something you expect it to do? Is it doing something you don't expect? What is your RequireJS config, and how do you start your application? (Edit your question with this information.)